# Adding plots to a frame in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, confusion-matrix

I am creating a GUI interface that requires user input to conduct a cross-validation assessment on a dataset, and displaying 2 visualisations. My question is how to display these inside the tkinter frame. There is no real nice way of putting the code in, without having to put all of it on here, as all the data is linked to the output of the below confusion matrix (and the program is over 430 lines of code as it is) but essentially, I have a confusion matrix of:

```
conf_matrix = [[33 8],
               [3 47]]
```

I know you can use ConfusionMatrixDisplay from sklearn.metrics to make the confusion matrix look a lot nicer, with coloured boxes, however, as I said above, really not sure how to put it into a frame inside my tkinter window, as I cannot find anywhere that explains the process of doing so.

I have tried to put it directly onto a canvas, but get an error saying that ConfusionMatrixDisplay doesn't have a set_canvas attribute.

The other visualisation is from matplotlib, however, I imagine that the process is the same to do this as well.

It is important to note too that the frame has used grid() throughout, as there are a lot of buttons, and it was just easier to grid it to make it look nice, so of course the graphs need to be able to be put in a grid if possible!

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: as I remeber in `matplotlib` documentation you should find example how to add plot to `tkinter`. Matplotlib has special widget for this. And this problem was few times on Stackoverflow so you should also see examples in some answers.

Comment: see some of my examples on GitHub [python-examples/tkinter/matplotlib](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/embed-matplotlib)

Comment: you can also use many Canvas and put in grid or you can use one canvas and draw in subplots - like in [this example](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/embed-matplotlib/minimal-examples)

Comment: in my examples I found also link to Matplot example: [Embedding in Tk](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html)